# How to play video in video player in xamarin forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-videoview

I am working in xamarin forms. I am trying to play video in Video Player. For the same I have used this sample code from github

https://github.com/xamarin/customer-success-samples/tree/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms/FormsNativeVideoPlayer

but problem is when I put "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" link to VideoPlayer_CustomRender.cs file Video is play properly. but when I put any youtube link this is not working and show me the error "Can't play this video". **I want to achieve this functionality specially in android.**

I can't understand what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the video player component on the Xamarin Forms component store. It allows you to render the native video player on iOS, Android, and Windows Phone.

It also allows you to **play YouTube videos** using an included XAML extension called `YouTubeVideoIdExtension`. Note that this is experimental since you should be using the official Google APIs to integrate and get the correct source URLs.

The code snippet below shows the simplest example of just dropping it in and using it. You also have the ability to hook into events like playing, paused, stopped, completed, etc. You can control volume, autoplay, and repeat among other things.

https://github.com/adamfisher/Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:o="clr-namespace:Octane.Xam.VideoPlayer;assembly=Octane.Xam.VideoPlayer"
             x:Class="VideoPlayerSamples.VideoPlayerBasicExamplePage"
             Title="Basic Video Player">

    <o:VideoPlayer Source="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" />

</ContentPage>
```

**Disclaimer:** This is my component.

Comment: Thanks for replay, I have already seen this link before but I don't want to purchase it.

Comment: If anyone else is interested, the project has moved here: https://github.com/adamfisher/Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer

Comment: @Adam the plugin works nicely. Thanks! Is there a way I can have full screen control on Android just like iOS?

Comment: @Adam this plugin gives me an error when I was playing video from local storage, Error in only android side https://github.com/adamfisher/Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer/issues/182

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [LibVLCSharp](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp). Free and opensource.

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer.

Comment: LibVLCSharp seems to be unusable until there's an easy way to play multiple videos in sequence or loop videos without deadlock issues. It's one issue but it's a breaking for many projects.

Comment: I don't think we have a bug report for that, so feel free to open one